# Using Storyboards, how to tell when user leaves a scene?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.6

I have an iPad app (XCode 4.6, Storyboards, UITabBarController and iOS 6.2).  I want to be able to tell when the user leaves a particular "scene" so I can save the data just entered.

I have looked and looked and found nothing; I'm pretty sure my search arguments were not correct, but I tried Google and SO.  So, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [viewWillDisappear:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW18) method.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    //Save data logic here 
}
```

Comment: Oh man... why did I not think of that?  It's getting late and I'm just not thinking... thank you so much; I really appreciate it!